# Simplifying anonymous methods for background worker

Tags: c#, delegates, backgroundworker, anonymous-function

I am attempting to make all my code from button clicks, run in a background worker. So I have the following template of code.

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker.DoWork += delegate
{
    //code
};
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
while (backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Just want to know if there is a way to simplify this code, so I am not effectively duplicating the same code block for all my buttons.

EDIT:
The typical code I am trying to run is along the lines of:

```
//Synchronous task
Wait(2000);
//Synchronous task
return taskResult ? "Success" : "Failure"
```

Comment: Do you have any familiarity with async and await? You could more easily put your handler code in async methods.

Comment: No real familiarity with it, but I have read it is recommended for NET 4.5. Just haven't taken the time to learn about it. Any advantages to it?

Comment: You kind of defeat the purpose of a background worker by looping on doevents.

Comment: My goal is really to just keep the GUI functional. Most task I am performing take 2-3 seconds. So they are long enough that they make the GUI freeze up, but not so long that I want to let them truly run in the background. What would be the correct method to achieve this?

Comment: @Mayura Vivekanandra Background worker would work, but Les is right, you don't need to do DoEvents. But async/await is almost just like writing synchronous code so it is easier once you understand it.

Comment: @Crowcoder I am a bit confused about how to use async in this context. Do i need to make the button click event point to a async method, or do I need to have a async Task I call inside my button event, and then put an await at the end so I know the result of my task.

Comment: @Mayura Vivekanandra if you need to get a result I would make the handlers async, call them without await at first, then catch the result after doing other work. Get to know [Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without more context, it's impossible to suggest very specific improvements. That said, for sure you can get rid of the `while` loop. Just use:

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker.DoWork += delegate
{
    //code
};
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Note that if you have code you want to execute when the `BackgroundWorker` task completes (a possible explanation for why you had that `while` loop in the first place), something like this will work (instead of using the `while` loop you had before):

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker.DoWork += delegate
{
    //code
};
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    // code to execute when background task is done
};
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

In modern C#, `BackgroundWorker` is nearly obsolete. The main benefit it provides now is convenient progress reporting, and that is actually easily obtained instead through the use of `Progress<T>`.

If you don't need to report progress, factoring your code to use `async`/`await` is easy:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    //code
});

// code to execute when background task is done
```

If you do need to report progress, it's only slightly harder:

```
Progress<int> progress = new Progress<int>();

progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, progressValue) =>
{
    // do something with "progressValue" here
};

await Task.Run(() =>
{
    //code

    // When reporting progress ("progressValue" is some hypothetical
    // variable containing the progress value to report...Progress<T>
    // is generic so you can customize to do whatever you want)
    progress.Report(progressValue);
});

// code to execute when background task is done
```

Finally, in some cases you might need the task to return a value. In that scenario, it would look more like this:

```
var result = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    //code

    // "someValue" would be a variable or expression having the value you
    // want to return. It can be of any type.
    return someValue;
});

// At this point in execution "result" now has the value returned by the
// background task. Note that in the above example, the method itself
// is anonymous and so you could just set a local variable at the end of the
// task; the value-returning syntax is more useful when you are calling an
// actual method that itself returns a value, and is especially useful when
// you are calling an `async` method that returns a value (i.e. you're not
// even using `Task.Run()` in the `await` statement.

// code to execute when background task is done
```

You can mix and match the above techniques as needed.

Comment: Thanks for this. Really couldn't get my head around how I needed to call my code anonymously with async.

Comment: One thing I still don't understand is why you dont need the async before the '() =>'. From my limited understanding, I thought you had to use the async keyword to allow then use of the await keyword. Also am i correct in saying I could use Task.Wait() instead of await? or does that not achieve the same result.

Comment: @MayuraVivekananda: "why you dont need the async before the '() =>'" -- the anonymous method (declared using that lambda syntax) is not itself calling `await`, which is why it doesn't need `async`. The whole task represented by that anonymous method is made asynchronous by wrapping it in a call to `Task.Run()`, but the method itself is run in its entirety in the single `Task` created by the `Run()` method.

Comment: @MayuraVivekananda: "I could use `Task.Wait()` instead of await?" -- no, that does not achieve the same result. If you were to call `Wait()`, then the code would block the current thread right there, not continuing to execute in that thread until the task completed. But `await` is exactly the opposite; it's the indication to the compiler that the current method should in fact _return_ after initiating the asynchronous operation, allowing the thread to continue execution (i.e. in the caller of the method). The rest of the method is executed later, when the asynchronous operation completes.